# java array through multiple methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
public class AccountRecord {
  public static final int MAXEMPLOYEES = 2;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strTemp = new String[MAXEMPLOYEES];
    Double[] hourTemp = new Double[MAXEMPLOYEES];
    Double[] rateTemp = new Double[MAXEMPLOYEES];
    EmployeeData[] employeeRec = new EmployeeData[MAXEMPLOYEES];
    EmployeeFile getEmployee = new EmployeeFile();
    int count;

    getEmployee.openFile();
    getEmployee.readFile();
    getEmployee.closeFile();

    for(count = 0; count < MAXEMPLOYEES; count++) {
        employeeRec[count] = new EmployeeData();

        strTemp[count] = getEmployee.getFullName(count);
        hourTemp[count] = getEmployee.getHours(count);
        rateTemp[count] = getEmployee.getRate(count);

        employeeRec[count].setName(strTemp[count]);
        employeeRec[count].setHours(hourTemp[count]);
        employeeRec[count].setRate(rateTemp[count]);
        employeeRec[count].setGross();
        employeeRec[count].setTax();
        employeeRec[count].setNet();
    }
```

Above, is part of my main file.

---

So what I'm trying to due is hold an array of accounts, and within that account holds the employees full name, hours, and payrate. I read from and input file and store those inputs into an array of String for the full name, and an array of doubles for hours and payrate.

The problem I'm getting is in my "employeedata" object file:

When I try to set FullName, hours, and payrate and print out these values, I get a null value.

P.S. This is my first time on stackoverflow and my first time asking for help with code. I apologize in advanced if this is terrible format and I will fix it right away for you guys if you need me to. I am currently learning Java on my own so I due not possess full knowledge of this language yet. Thank you.

EDIT: @racraman I've managed to fixed my previous problem and now is just a quick answer about efficiency. As you can see in my code above, I am storing values from 'getEmployee" into my temporary arrays(strTemp, hourTemp, rateTemp) to hold them. Then I am storing these values into 'employeeRec[count]'. I have a hunch that there is a better way to go about what I'm trying to do here. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to find out what is happend?

Comment: There's a highly suspicious `*/` in your code. Also, you are never changing `record` . Edit this, making sure that your code is OK

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues :

- Firstly, I notice an end-comment "*/" after your first for loop (the one with 
  System.out.println("Enter first and last name: "); ).  I take it this loop is supposed to commented out - yes?
- Secondly - sounds minor, but best to get with standards early on - In Java, class names are "camel-case" - ie. the beginnings of each word are capitalised - so "EmployeeData" instead of "employeedata".  Ditto variable names, except they have lower-case first letter - e.g. "firstName"

The actual problem is that you have EmployeeData "doing" too much - it's both the file, and also the values for each employee.  So, when you do :
    r.openFile();
    r.readFile();
    r.closeFile();

you're reading the file into variable "r".  However, those values are not available to the "employee[record]" variables, since they're different objects unrelated to "r".

What you should do is split EmployeeData into two classes :
- class EmployeeFile to encapsulate all the file handling, and
- class Employee to hold the attributes for each employee

Comment: Yes. That first loop was supposed to be commented out because I was taking input from the keyboard at first, but wanted to try file input. So if I use 2 classes would I have to declare my variables public so that both classes can access each other?

Comment: You'd have a couple of options.  I don't like public variables - that's exposing the "mechanics" of the class.  Rather, think of  what the class DOES - the functionality that is the reason callers will use the class.  Then expose THAT behaviour as public methods (a good practice is to have an explicit "public interface" - google "Program to an interface") , keeping the variables and details of how it does it as private.  For example, you could have "Employee getEmployee(int recNum)", or maybe separate getters for each field - whatever makes sense in the situation.